# Cython: C-level int vs. PyLongObjects

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, integer, cython

I'm reading the book "Cython" written by Kurt W. Smith. I'm confused by this book.

On page 42 the author said:

> In cases where Python built-in types like int or float have the same name as a C type, the C type takes precedence. This is almost always what we want.

However on page 44, the author said:

> Python also has a PyLongObject at the C level to represent arbitrarily
> sized integers. In Python 2, these are exposed as the long type, and
> if an operation with PyIntObject overflows, a PyLongObject results.
>
> In Python 3, at the C level, all integers are PyLongObjects.

My question is if I declared a variable in Python 3, say

```
cdef int a;
```

Is `a` a C-level `int` because C type takes precedence, or a `PyLongObject`?

If it's a C-level `int`, how to interpret the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cdef int a` declares a C-level integer in both Python 2 and 3; the C type takes precedence.

All the author appears to be saying is that `int` in *pure* Python 3 always means the `PyLongObject` type. There is no distinction between Python `int` and `long` numerical types now.

Python 2 had the [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) type to mean `PyLongObject` types, but this has been removed in Python 3 which just has `int` to refer to `PyLongObject` types. Therefore there is no potential conflict with builtin types when you write `cdef long a` when using Cython with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to questions of this kind is to just give it a try and see what happens:

```
$ cat > foo.pyx
cdef int mytestint
mytestint = 1
$ cython foo.pyx 
$ grep mytestint foo.c | head -n 1
static int __pyx_v_3foo_mytestint;
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know this approach. But would you please explain how to interpret those two paragraphs?